# Why am I unable to connect Sql server 2008 R2 from tibco BW?

Tags: sql-server-2008, tibco

When I'm trying to connect to sql server from tibco JDBC connection getting the following errors.
For `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

```
 BW-JDBC-100034 "Configuration Test Failed. Exception     [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException] occurred. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Software caused connection abort: recv  failed"
```

and for `tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver`

```
BW-JDBC-100033 "Configuration Test Failed. Failed to find or load the JDBC driver: tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"
```

I've placed the jar files in `C:\tibco\tpcl\5.7\lib` folder and also tried by placing the jar files in `C:\tibco\tpcl\5.7\jdbc` folder.

Can any please let me know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you should put the jar files in **tibco bw/lib** folder.

For me its `C:\tibco\bw\5.10\lib`

Additionally if you want to connect ms sql  server using windows authentication then you also have to keep **windows/system32** folder or add to class path.

Comment: I'm getting this error message BW-JDBC-100033 "Configuration Test Failed. Failed to find or load the JDBC driver:tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"

Comment: @Lax_me I think you may not have installed the proper driver.I tested with mysql and ms sql server both working fine.If you want I can provide the screenshot also

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC drivers should be placed in:

```
C:\tibco\tpcl\5.7\jdbc
```

You must create the `jdbc` folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I've created this folder earlier and placed the jars in it but I got the same above mentioned errors

Comment: There used to be a bug in some releases of BW. Which version are you using?

Comment: Can you confirm that the `%TPCL_HOME%/jdbc` entry exists in the `tibco.env.STD_EXT_CP` classpath in your designer.tra?

Comment: In my designer has   `tibco.env.STD_CP_EXT` classpath and this `tibco.env.STD_EXT_CP` not exixts

Comment: Sorry I meant `tibco.env.STD_CP_EXT`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Its resolved now.

First - Check If you are able to connect to a different Sql server using the JDBC connection in Tibco designer. If yes - there is an issue with the Sql server in your machine.
You should upgrade to Sql Server 2008 Service Pack 2. I did, restarted my Sql server and was able to connect. Download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437). Also you need to make sure you have the jdbc folder in your C:\tibco\tpcl\5.7\ and you have the corresponding class path tibco.env.STD_CP_EXT in the designer.tra.

Just FYI, a relevant fix is in in SP2 patch:-

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2653857

FIX: You cannot connect to SQL Server by using JDBC Driver for SQL Server after you upgrade to JRE 6 update 29 or a later version