# TIBCO JDBC ERROR BW-JDBC-100034

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, tibco

I am trying to connect to my local MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 using JDBC.  I get the following error

> BW-JDBC-100034 "Configuration Test Failed. Exception [java.sql.SQLException] occurred.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

I have already verified the following

1. SQLJDBC.jar is in the path TIBCO_HOME\tpcl\5.8\jdbc & TIBCO_HOME\tpcl\5.8\LIB
2. The classpath tibco.env.STD_CP_EXT is set to the path TIBCO_HOME\JDBC in the designer.tra file.

Still I get the BW-JDBC-100034 error.  Kindly advise

Comment: [Why am I unable to connect Sql server 2008 R2 from tibco BW?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185872/why-am-i-unable-to-connect-sql-server-2008-r2-from-tibco-bw)

Comment: The problem is fixed and following are the steps to clear it

1. Download the sqljdbc4.jar as i was using JDBC4 & JRE 1.7
2. Place this in TIBCO_HOME/tpcl/5.8/JDBC
3. Refer this in classpath of designre.tra file
4. Enable your SQL SERVER To accept TCP/IP connections(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)
5. Restart the sql server

Comment: If you found an answer useful in the linked question you might upvote these answer(s)

Comment: If you found an own answer, please add it as answer and accept it. Answering own questions is totally fine on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the jdbc driver you are using in this JDBC Connection activity? If you are using Microsoft driver you have to use the sqljdbc4.jar as you have already used. If you are using a tibco driver however, you need the TISql.jar which you can obtain by installing the product TIBCO-dbdrivers-2.0 from download.tibco.com.

Happy that you were able to fix the issue.